# graphicsmagick : Depends: libgraphicsmagick-q16-3

Tags: 16.04

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 graphicsmagick : Depends: libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 (>= 1.3.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I found the package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgraphicsmagick-q16-3

However I still can't seem to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick-q16-3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgraphicsmagick-q16-3
```

Comment: The package in question is in the universe repository. Have you enabled the universe repo?

Answer (score 0):

The package I was looking for is located in the `universe` repo, quoted in bold here:

> Package: libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 (1.3.23-1build1) [**universe**]

This adds not just the `universe` repo but the `main`, `restricted` and `multiverse` and for which ever version of Ubuntu you have.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```